# Evaluating integral with respect to brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-integrals

I am attempting to integrate

$$ \int _{0}^{t} \sin(s) dW_s $$

whereas $W_s$ is brownian motion, in some sense a normal random variable with mean 0 and variance $s$.

I looked around in stack exchange and I couldn't really find a clear solution.

One idea I had was using Ito's formula (Which really I want to believe is overkill given it appears much later in the text). If I can convert $\sin(s) dW_s$ to $dE(s,W_s)$ then I just integrate to yield $E(s,W_s)$ (and then something has to be set to $t$ and something else to $0$ and subtracted but i'll defer that part of the problem to when I get there).

Ito's formula gives:

$$ df(s,W_s) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_s} dW_s +\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial W_s ^2 } dS +\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} dS $$

So if $df(s,W_s) = \sin(s) dW_s$ then it must be the case that

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial W_s ^2 } dS = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} dS $$

And

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_s} dW_s = \sin(s) dW_s$$

I notice this implies

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_s} = \sin(s) \rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_s^2} = 0 \rightarrow f = \sin(s)W_s + C(s)$$

But we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = 0 \rightarrow C(s) = K + \cos(s)W_s$

and this is where things fall apart.

So I conclude that Ito's was not only overkill, but at least the way I approached, a dumb strategy overall. So how should I tackle this alternatively?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "integrate" (a stochastic integral)? What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: Indeed, except that computing this is a centered normal random variable with mean $____$, what do you expect?

Comment: I had seen this integral in the context of computing $E[e^{\int_{0}^{t} \sin(s) dW_s } ] $ , perhaps my gut intuition of evaluating the integral was flawed?

Comment: *Typo: centered normal random variable with _variance_ etc.

Comment: @Did computing the integral is the same things as computing a centered a normal variable? I don't follow. Here's my exact sequence of thoughts: 1. "what is computing a centered normal variable? I've heard of computing metrics like expectation but computing the variable itself i don't quite understand", 2. Once I know what 1 means how do I reduce my integral to 1? and I suppose that it will become clear how the variance plays a role once i'm there,

Comment: Let me rephrase: to "integrate" the stochastic integral in your question has no meaning; to compute its distribution has a meaning and is straightforward. Once one knows the distribution is centered normal with variance $\sigma^2$, one gets $$E\left(\exp\left(\int_0^t\sin(s)\,dW_s\right)\right)=E\left(e^{\sigma Z}\right),$$ where $Z$ is standard normal, and *that* should be easy.

Comment: Okay, and so how did you deduce that the distribution is centered normal?  and is $\sigma$ being inherited as the same $\sigma$ in $W_s$?